# cygwin : pdksh(5.2.14-3) doesn't support backslash path (\)

Tags: unix, cygwin, ksh, backslash, pdksh

as an replacement for ksh under cygwin, pdksh might be the only choice. but look like there have a bug for cygwin : pdksh(5.2.14-3) to support backslash path (\).

it will swallow the \ :

```
$ cd .\access
pdksh: cd: /cygdrive/e/.access - No such file or directory
```

After search on the internet, the same problem solved for other platform. but no idea how to solve it for cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

Pdksh, like all Cygwin programs, does support backslashes as directory separators. But you have to quote them properly. Running shell scripts under Cygwin really teaches you to quote things properly, in particular to **always put variable substitutions in double quotes**, and not use echo carelessly (`printf "%s" "$x"` is portable and reliable: unlike `echo`, there's no risk that it might do backslash expansion).

Note that pdksh's compatibility with even ksh88 is far from perfect, so some scripts may fail for other reasons (such as relying on the status code of `writer | reader` being that of `reader`, which is the case in true ksh but not in pdksh). Cygwin includes `zsh`, which after you run `emulate ksh` is mostly compatible with ksh88 (though still not perfect).

There are non-Cygwin ports of ksh for Windows, including <strike><strike>Interix</strike>[SFU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_Services_for_UNIX)</strike>[SUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsystem_for_UNIX-based_Applications) and [ATT's own port](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use forward slashes, or double all the backslashes, or single-quote every string that might be a pathname.  Sorry, there's no way around this.  This is a general problem with trying to use Unix shells, for which \ is an escape character, on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Cygwin User's Guide](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html):

> #### Note
>
> The usage of Win32 paths, though possible, is deprecated, since it circumvents important internal path handling mechanisms. See [the section called “Using native Win32 paths”](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-win32) and [the section called “Using the Win32 file API in Cygwin applications”](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-win32-api) for more information.

There is a utility called [`cygpath`](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#cygpath) that is designed to be used in shell scripts that converts each way between Win32 and POSIX paths.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround for the problem. Start using bash and make the following modifications in config files.

- Open ~/.bashrc
- Add the following code at the end

  ```
  wcd() 
  {  
      cd $(echo "$@" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')   
  }
  ```
- Save it
- Reload bash terminal.
- Type

  ```
  wcd ".\access"
  ```

  along with the quotes and voila, you have your own windows compatible cd command.